# hash function for 5 tuple - ipv4/6

Tags: c, networking, hash, hashtable

I'm looking for an efficient hash function for ipv4/6 (it can be 2 separated functions, one for each family)

I came across this question: [hash function for src dest ip + port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215232/hash-function-for-src-dest-ip-port)

How do I extend it to support ipv6?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IPV4 I used following function:

```
uint32_t *S_block = ... 
// pointer to 1KB+ pre-defined random values.
// It can be reference to program code segment, or to long "help" string.
// For example, see: https://github.com/EvgenijM86/emercoin/blob/master/src/stun.cpp#L338

uint32_t HashIPV4(uint32_t x) {
  x += x >> 13;
  for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    x += ((x << 11) | (x >> (32 - 11))) ^ S_block[(unsigned char)x];
  x += x >> 17;
  return x;
}
```

For IPV6, you can use modification:

```
uint32_t HashIPV6(uint32_t *p) {
  x = 0x55555555;
  for(int i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
    x = ((x << 11) | (x >> (32 - 11))); 
    x += p[i & 3] ^ S_block[(unsigned char)x];
  }
  x += x >> 33;
  return x;
}
```

Comment: @maxihaptop - It would really help if you explained your code (method).

Comment: Cyclic shift hash-accumulator, with applying non-linear function by  Substitute Block.