# Is there an algorithm for keying a structure as a Zobrist key?

Tags: c, algorithm

Sorry in advance if my question is unclear.

I have a structure, representing a unique ID of a network entity in my program:

```
struct key {
   uint32_t src_ip;
   uint32_t dst_ip;
   uint16_t src_port;
   uint16_t dst_port;
   uint32_t user_num;
}
```

I would like to use that structure to key the network entities in a hash table.

Now, the structure is 16 bytes, meaning I'll have to save 16 bytes in the table.

I recently learned about Zobrist key, and I think it can be useful here (to save space, and perhaps reduce hash calculation time).

Is there an algorithm I can use to generate a Zobrist key from my key structure? I.E convert it efficiently into a 64 bit value which is 99.99% unique, considering the amount of entities I have simultaneously in the hash table.

Once again, sorry if unclear and if I'm asking nonsense.

Thanks,

Comment: You can directly go for a five- tupe hash function.[hash function for src dest ip + port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215232/hash-function-for-src-dest-ip-port)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually like mentioned in comment I can use a 5-tuple hash as the (likely) unique key instead of storing the entire 5-tuple.