# How to hash 5-tuple (SRC IP - SRC Port - DST IP - DST Port - Procotol )

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash

I am storing the network connections in a PCAP file as 5 tuple, and doing so many search in that list with Python. However trivial solution which compares all 5 values to each other is dramatically slow.
My list has Session objects which stores the following data,
SrcIP : 192.168.0.1
SrcPort : 443
DstIP : 192.168.0.101
DstPort : 5000
Protocol: TCP
I want to create a hash function in python that generates a unique hash value for each session (5 tuple) and store only that value. I read the following questions : 
[Hash function for SRC DST IP and Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215232/hash-function-for-src-dest-ip-port)
But still curious about the solution that can be achieved with default python modules like ipaddress and hashlib.

I have tried ipaddress module and end up with 5 different values like following :

```
import ipaddress

ip1 = ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.1')
ip2 = ipaddress.ip_address('255.255.255.255')
port1 = 445
port2 = 5001
protocol = 'tcp'
print(int(ip1))
print(int(ip2))
print(port1)
print(port2)
print(protocol)
```

Which prints out the following :

```
3232235777
4294967295
445
5001
tcp
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried ipaddress module and I think I will start my solution with this.

Comment: Show us some code you wrote!

Answer (score 2):

Quick and simple: exploit python's [`hash`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/hash) on a string built with your values:

```
key = '{};{};{};{};{}'.format(src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port, protocol)
hashed_key = hash(key)
```

Example:

```
key = '192.168.0.1;443;192.168.0.101;5000;TCP'
print(hash(key))
```

prints

```
2213561766848318588
```

For more control on the hashing function, have a look at [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)